# How to wrap text in Dialog

Tags: java, dialog, codenameone, word-wrap

I'm trying to wrap the text in a Dialog, but I couldn't find the way. I tried with \n but it is not working.
[image]
[image]

Where am I wrong?
Thanks in advance for any answer.
Luca

Comment: Please show the relevant code, I mean the text, not an image.

Comment: Hi, I hope my answer is satisfying...

Comment: You can use `StringUtil` replace for `"\\n"` to `"\n"` which will replace your \n entries with actual newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved thanks to Shai Almog's comment.
That's the relevant code:

```
Dialog.show(lg.nome, StringUtil.replaceAll(lg.testo,"\\n","\n") + "\n (da: " + lg.libro + ", pag." + lg.pagina + ")", "Chiudi",null);}
```

It works fine, and I can wrap the text from the XML file as I need.

Bye
Luca

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mario Santini.
This is the code:

```
// costruttore 
public Luogo(String libro,String id,String nome,String indirizzo,String lat,String lng,String testo,String pagina,String icona){

    this.ID = Integer.parseInt(id.substring(1, id.length()-2)); 
    this.nome=nome.substring(1, nome.length()-2);
    this.indirizzo=indirizzo.substring(1, indirizzo.length()-2);
    this.lat=Double.parseDouble(lat.substring(1, lat.length()-2));
    this.lng=Double.parseDouble(lng.substring(1, lng.length()-2));
    this.testo=testo.substring(1, testo.length()-2);
    this.libro=libro;
    this.pagina=Integer.parseInt(pagina.substring(1, pagina.length()-2));
    this.icona=icona.substring(1, icona.length()-2);    
} 

public void aggiungiLuogoMappa(MapContainer map){
    Luogo lg = this;
    Coord coord=new Coord(this.lat,this.lng);
    EncodedImage icon;

    try {
        icon =EncodedImage.create("/" + this.icona);    
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //nel caso di errore aggiungo il marker standard
        Style st = new Style();
        st.setFgColor(0xff0000);
        st.setBgTransparency(0);

        FontImage markerImg = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_PLACE, st, Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(1)); 
        icon =EncodedImage.createFromImage(markerImg, false);
    }
    map.addMarker(icon, coord,this.nome + " - " + this.indirizzo, null, new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        Dialog.show(lg.nome, lg.testo + "\n (da: " + lg.libro + ", pag." + lg.pagina + ")", "Chiudi",null);}
    });
}
```

}

The \n works well if I put it in the code (see last row), but I would like also that lg.testo could be wrapped where I need. lg.testo comes from an xml file that looks like this:
[image]

The final result is this:
[image]